# How to fix the Python Selenium CSV file loop problem?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

I'm trying to create a script for loop from the CSV file to filling up the website email and password.
But the loop is only stuck at the first ROW, can't go to the next ROW. Anyone can help?

1. Open Browser
2. Go to a website
3. Auto Log-in (filling up email and password details from csv file )
4. Close Browser
5. Re open again the website(loop start from the second step )
6. Re Auto log-in but with the second account (filling up details from csv file SECOND ROW ) .

Re do the same tasks 50 times (From account 1 to 50 for example )

**I am running Python 3.8.1 and PyCharm.**

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

chrome.get("https://facebook.com")


data = pd.read_csv(r'D:\PyCharm\test.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

i = 0
while i == 0:
    a = 0

    Username = df.username
    Password = df.password

    id_box = chrome.find_element_by_id('email')
    id_box.send_keys(Username[a])

    Pass_box = chrome.find_element_by_id('pass')
    Pass_box.send_keys(Password[a])

    Send = chrome.find_element_by_name('login')
    Send.click()

    try:
        test = chrome.find_element_by_id('pass')
        id_box.clear()
        Pass_box.clear()

    except:
        print("logged in")
        break
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: Does the code above works fine and you are trying just to loop it 50 times?